# how to filter record from sales id (create uid) just only for scpecific merchant based on them sales

Tags: xml, filter, odoo-9

i just want to make merchant id only can view who them sales id related.

i try make this filter for merchant it will they just see what them sales created record. but this is still error. i still learn in odoo, please help me to know what must i do from my problem?

```
<filter string="VP ROLE" name="approved_contract_merchant" domain="[('create_uid','=',logged_user_id)]"/>
```

This is my eror when im try that filter

```
Error: Failed to evaluate search criterions: 
{"code":400,"message":"Evaluation Error","data":{"type":"local_exception","debug":"Local evaluation failure\nNameError: name 'logged_user_id' is not defined\n\n{\"domains\":[[[\"create_uid\",\"=\",1]],\"[('create_uid','=',logged_user_id)]\"],\"contexts\":[{\"lang\":\"en_US\",\"tz\":false,\"uid\":1,\"search_default_approved_contract_merchant\":3,\"default_approved_contract_merchant\":3,\"params\":{\"action\":816}},{}],\"group_by_seq\":[]}"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

```
<filter string="VP ROLE" name="approved_contract_merchant" domain="[('create_uid','=',uid)]"/>
```

*or*

```
<filter string="VP ROLE" name="approved_contract_merchant" domain="[('create_uid','=',user.id)]"/>
```